# how do i can handle select xpath into iframe without select tag

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, automation

the code is into iframe and i need to enter, or select value from dropdown.

But when i'm trying to send value i get an error like this:

```
Find element :By.xpath: //div[@class='filterWrapper_1rqdl1n-o_O-filterWrapper_noFilter_rn3gmd']
Get Exception: invalid element state
```

or if trying select value from dropdown i get that slector should be select instead of div..

there is css code:

[image]

and there is my code:

```
 private static By inputUsername = By.xpath("//div[@class='filterWrapper_1rqdl1n-o_O-filterWrapper_noFilter_rn3gmd']");

    @Step("Enter document number")
    public MainPage enterLoginTab(String value) {
        fields.type(inputUsername,value);
        //dropDown.selectDropDownByValue(inputUsername, value);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. You can copy the HTML directly from the console in the browser. Just right click on an HTML tag and then copy outer HTML. Then [edit] your question, paste the code, highlight and click the format as code icon in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the xpath as
`"//div[@class[contains(.,'label_kohvda)]][@role='button']"'`

Also check if there is an input stage element is there in DOM for select Tab number, if yes then use that XPath and enter the value using sendKeys and due to autocomplete when suggestion element appears you may add that element XPath bypassing the element value as dynamic and use click method on it.